# How to convert $z^2 = \theta y^2$ to second order cone constraint?

Tags: optimization, second-order-cone-programming

I have difficulties converting a constraint to a SOC constraint. Here is the full problem:

\begin{align}
  \text{minimize}  &\quad \alpha \nonumber\\
  \text{subject to}   
   &\quad \sum_{P_j \in \Pi_i} x_{ij} = 1 & (1)\\
   &\quad y_{ik} = \sum_{P_j \in \Pi_i} x_{ij} \mathbf{I}_{L_k \in P_j} & (2)\\
   &\quad \sum_{L_k \in P_j} \varepsilon_k \le \epsilon & (3)\\
   &\quad \big( 2 \ln\frac{1}{\varepsilon_k} \big)
    \sum_{F_i} \sigma^2_i y^2_{ik} \le \Big( \alpha C_k - \sum_{F_i} \mu_i y_{ik} \Big)^2 & (4)\\
   &\quad 0 \le x_{ij} \le 1 \\
   &\quad 0 \le y_{ik} \le 1 \\
   &\quad 0 \le \varepsilon_k \le 1
\end{align}

Problem is Constraint (4), which can be stated as below:
\begin{equation}
   \theta \sum_{i} y_i^2 \le u^2,
\end{equation}
where $0 \le y_i \le 1$, $\theta \ge 0$, and $u \ge 0$ are optimization variables. If $\theta$ was not present, the constraint would be a standard SOC constraint.

I have the following, 
\begin{align}
    \theta y_i^2 \le z_i^2 \Rightarrow \sum_{i} z_i^2 \le u^2
\end{align}
which is now a SOC constraint, if the following is correct:
\begin{align}
    &\theta y_i^2 \le z_i^2 \\
 &\equiv
      y_i^2 \le \frac{1}{\theta} z_i^2 \\
 &\equiv
 \begin{cases} 
  y_i^2 \le t z_i^2\\
  \frac{1}{\theta} \le t
 \end{cases} \qquad(1)\\
 &\equiv
 \begin{cases} 
  y_i^2 \le t w_i\\
  z_i^2 \le w_i\\
  1 \le \theta t
\end{cases} \qquad(2)
\end{align}

The final system of inequalities can be easily converted to standard cone constraints
\begin{equation}
\equiv
\begin{cases} 
4 y_i^2  + (t - w_i)^2 \le (t + w_i)^2\\
4 z_i^2 + (1 - w_i)^2 \le (1+w_i)^2\\
4 + (\theta - t)^2 \le (\theta + t)^2
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Question: Are the inequalities in steps (1) and (2) equivalent to the original constraint? Any comment is appreciated.

Comment: It seems that $w$ in (2) is not bounded. You want $w_i \leq z_i^2$. I deleted my original answer because it does not apply to your current question. I do not think your constraint is representable. If you show your entire problem, maybe there it can be reformulated.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, It should be $w_i \le z_i^2$. The rest of the program has only linear constraints. I have updated my question to show the whole program. As you can see, problem is Constraint (4), which is what I have been trying to convert to a SOC constraint.

Comment: If $\theta, y, z$ are all variables then $\theta y^2\leq z^2$ is not SOCP representable. If it was, then in conjunction with $z^2\leq y$ you could model $\theta y\leq 1$ which obviously you can't. Your last transformation does not work because the inequality $\frac{1}{\theta}\leq t$ needs to be written the other way around.